# Connect to Team Foundation Server from Azure Data Studio

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-sql-database, azure-repos, azure-data-studio

I have connected team foundation server with Visual studio 2017 for source control using the team explorer plug in.

I am trying to do the same with azure data studio. The main purpose is to add source control for the database objects like stored procedures and triggers.

I am trying to connect Azure data studio with team foundation server so that I can use the azure repos for source control. I couldn't find a way to do so, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [Azure Repos](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) extension for Visual Studio Code - The **Download Extension** link on that page will give you the .vsix file.
Then in Azure Data Studio run the **Extensions: install from VSIX** action and pick the file you just downloaded. This will provide you with TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) support and more.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Studio support only Git as Source Control. you can't "connect" to TFS like in Visual Studio, but you can connect local git repository and then commit & push the changes to TFS.

If you are using TFS with TFVC (not Git) you can't manage the database objects with TFS source control.

More info about how using Azure Data Studio with Git you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/source-control).